# Debian image build from Ubuntu launchpad

Tags: ubuntu, debian, debian-based

I downloaded the building scripts and some needed files to build debian cd image from the following link

[Debian_CD](https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-cdimage/debian-cd/ubuntu)

In the README, it mentions I should edit the PATHs for the mirror.
At CONF.sh

```
# Paths to the mirrors
export MIRROR=${MIRROR:-$CDIMAGE_ROOT/ftp}

# Comment the following line if you don't have/want non-US
#export NONUS=/ftp/debian-non-US

# Path of the temporary directory
export TDIR=$CDIMAGE_ROOT/scratch/$PROJECT/$DIST/$IMAGE_TYPE/tmp
# Path where the images will be written
export OUT=$CDIMAGE_ROOT/scratch/$PROJECT/$DIST/$IMAGE_TYPE/debian-cd

# Where we keep the temporary apt stuff.
# This cannot reside on an NFS mount.
export APTTMP=$CDIMAGE_ROOT/scratch/$PROJECT/$DIST/$IMAGE_TYPE/apt

# Where extracted debootstrap scripts live
export DEBOOTSTRAP=$CDIMAGE_ROOT/scratch/$PROJECT/$DIST/$IMAGE_TYPE/debootstrap

# Where live filesystem images live
export LIVEIMAGES=$CDIMAGE_ROOT/scratch/$PROJECT/$DIST/$IMAGE_TYPE/live
```

I am not really sure what does the "**mirror**" refer to and how to set the **path** correctly ?

Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MIRROR` refers to the APT software repository (usually a *mirror* of Debian maintained one, to save bandwidth and downloading time) for live-build to retrieve software components to make the live system from.

It's *usually* in the following form(take ubuntu as an example, but the url is slightly different):

`http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu`

So in my case just modify the CONF.sh's

`export MIRROR=${MIRROR:-$CDIMAGE_ROOT/ftp}`

to

`export MIRROR=http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu`

You can find out the urls required by checking out the software mirror section on the Debian's site.